# Cannot run JMX Exporter in Wildfly 17 running on Java 11

Tags: java, wildfly, java-11, jmx-exporter, wildfly-17

Currently we're running Wildfly (version 17.0.1.Final) in a self-created Docker image based on Java 8. For monitoring our application via Prometheus we installed `jmx_exporter` and configured it as shown below.

Now we'd like to switch to the official Docker image `jboss/wildfly:17.0.1.Final` which however uses Java 11. When using our current configuration the JVM cannot be created because `-Xbootclasspath/p` is not supported anymore. Only `-Xbootclasspath/a` or `-Xbootclasspath` are valid.

Just replacing `-Xbootclasspath/p` with `-Xbootclasspath/a` does not work and gives the following error message upon startup:

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:239)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:223)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:223)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:648)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:717)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:701)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector.<clinit>(JmxCollector.java:38)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
```

#### Configuration for Java 8

(excerpt from our `Dockerfile`)

```
# Prometheus (JMX Exporter)
# Versions must match those provided by application server.
# https://lazarbulic.com/blog/2018/05/25/prometheus-jmx_exporter-for-jboss-wildfly/
# We need to add these JARs explicitly to avoid a NoClassDefFoundError.
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874743/noclassdeffounderror-when-using-jmx-exporter-with-wildfly-15
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/wildfly/common/main/wildfly-common-$WILDFLY_COMMON_VERSION.jar"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-$JBOSS_LOG_MANAGER_VERSION.jar"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-$LOG4J_JBOSS_LOGMANAGER_VERSION.jar"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-$SLF4J_JBOSS_LOGMANAGER_VERSION.jar"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JBOSS_MANAGEMENT_PORT -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JBOSS_MANAGEMENT_PORT  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
ENV PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$JBOSS_HOME/prometheus/jmx-prometheus.jar=$PROMETHEUS_PORT:$JBOSS_HOME/prometheus/config.yaml"
```

Comment: The question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529593)